# Efficient filesystem searching

Tags: c, linux, gcc, performance, filesystems

I am writing a program which searches through all the sub-directories of a given directory. The problem is, is that I know the name of the file that I am looking for (data.txt) but I still need to know all of the (possibly multiple) locations where the file is. I am using this code to search:

```
struct dirent *dp;
struct stat s;
DIR *dir;

char path[]="/some/path/here/";

if((dir=opendir(path))==NULL){return;}

while((dp=readdir(dir))!=NULL){

  char *temp=malloc((strlen(path)+strlen(dp->d_name)+4)*sizeof(*temp));
  sprintf(temp,"%s%s",path,dp->d_name);//concatenate path

  lstat(temp,&s);//stat the path

  if(S_ISREG(s.st_mode)){//if regular file
    if(!strcmp(dp->d_name,"data.txt")){
      printf("found one: %s\n",temp);//found the target file
    }

  }else if(S_ISDIR(s.st_mode) && !S_ISLNK(s.st_mode)){//if directory, but not symlink
    if(strcmp(dp->d_name,".") && strcmp(dp->d_name,"..")){//ignore "." and ".."
      //recurse on the subdirectories
    }

  }


  free(temp);

}
closedir(dir);
```

The code works fine and its still very fast, but I still feels that it's very inefficient to be `lstat`-ing every file/directory in the filesystem just to look for directories.

Is there a more efficient way of searching so that only directories are returned via `readdir`?

I'm using gcc on Fedora 13

Comment: I assume you are aware of the `locate` command line utility?  It uses a periodically updated database (`updatedb`).

Comment: I think that the `opendir` / `readdir` functions may be using that behind the scenes. On a first-time search, my code can search my 100Gb disk in ~10seconds, the second time runs in under 2seconds. The find command exhibits the same behavior when run multiple times.

Comment: @jdkomo: that's the filesystem cache in action, not usage of `updatedb`

Comment: Check out this previous question.  My answer (which was not chosen) has some info on avoiding calls to `stat` or `fstat` under Linux for some filesystems.  Additionally you can just try to `opendir` or `open(direntry_name, O_DIRECTORY | )` them all (except for `.` and `..` or maybe all hidden) and only work on the ones that pass.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560614/alternatives-to-using-stat-to-get-file-type/2564304#2564304

Answer (score 2):

ftw() (or nftw() ) are the calls to implement a find-like function.

The reason stat or lstat is required is to know what file type you have - regular, link,
directory, etc.

It is possible, though not likely at all, to have "data.txt" be a directory, a link, and a regular file.  You have to be able to sort it out to get what you want.  ftw() returns a stat struct * to a callback function - which is an argument to ftw().

Comment: This function calls stat behind the scenes, so they are most likely doing the same thing. I was just curious if there was a function that returned only the directories, and skipped over files altogether.

Comment: Yes, there is - you write it as your callback function.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `lstat` on each returned value, use the `dirent`'s `d_type` field (see [`readdir`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/readdir.3.html) man page), eg.

```
while((dp=readdir(dir))!=NULL){
    ...
    if (dp->d_type == DT_REG)
    {
      /* handle regular file */
    }
    else if (dp->d_type == DT_DIR)
    {
      /* handle directory */
    }
}
```

Comment: I was actually doing exactly that at first. I switched to my current implementation after reading on http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir that `According to POSIX, the dirent structure contains a field char d_name[] of unspecified size, (...) Use of other fields will harm the portability of your programs.`

Comment: @jdkomo: if you're targetting linux, just go with this. it's by far the easiest to bolt on to what you have, and the least invasive. Recommend you check for `_DIRENT_HAVE_D_TYPE` as mentioned in the NOTES, and adjust accordingly.

Comment: @Matt Joiner, I was never targeting windows, so this may work out fine. I assumed that when they referred to portability, they meant cross-distro, Ubuntu/Fedora/etc and not Linux/Windows. Thanks.

Comment: I also recommend using the `d_type` field.  I have used this in some of my Cygwin-based Windows apps as well and have had no problems there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read sources of a linux `find` command.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [`glob`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob) function, it sounds like you might be trying to re-implement it.